# How to unpersist in Sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, persistence, sparklyr

I am using `Sparklyr` for a project and have understood that persisting is very useful. I am using `sdf_persist` for this, with the following syntax (correct me if I am wrong):

```
data_frame <- sdf_persist(data_frame)
```

Now I am reaching a point where I have too many RDDs stored in memory, so I need to unpersist some. However I cannot seem to find the function to do this in `Sparklyr`. Note that I have tried:

```
dplyr::db_drop_table(sc, "data_frame")
dplyr::db_drop_table(sc, data_frame)
unpersist(data_frame)
sdf_unpersist(data_frame)
```

But none of those work.

Also, I am trying to avoid using `tbl_cache` (in which case it seems that `db_drop_table` works) as it seems that `sdf_persist` offers more liberty on the storage level. It might be that I am missing the big picture of how to use persistence here, in which case, I'll be happy to learn more.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about granularity then the simplest solution is to invoke `Catalog.clearCache`:

```
spark_session(sc) %>% invoke("catalog") %>% invoke("clearCache")
```

Uncaching specific object is much less straightforward due to `sparklyr` indirection. If you check the object returned by `sdf_cache` you'll see that the persisted table is not exposed directly:

```
df <- copy_to(sc, iris, memory=FALSE, overwrite=TRUE) %>% sdf_persist()

spark_dataframe(df) %>% 
  invoke("storageLevel") %>% 
  invoke("equals", invoke_static(sc, "org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel", "NONE"))
```

```
[1] TRUE
```

That's beacuase you don't get registered table directly, but rather a result of subquery like `SELECT * FROM ...`.

It means you cannot simply call `unpersist`:

```
spark_dataframe(df) %>% invoke("unpersist")
```

as you would in one of the official API's.

Instead you can try to retrieve the name of the source table, for example like this

```
src_name <- as.character(df$ops$x)
```

and then invoke `Catalog.uncacheTable`:

```
spark_session(sc) %>% invoke("catalog") %>% invoke("uncacheTable", src_name)
```

That is likely not the most robust solution, so please use with caution.